# Use powershell to split a list

Tags: powershell

I would like to take a list of names split with returns and put each item in quotes with a comma.

**Example of list:**

test

test2

test3

**Desired outcome:**

'test',

'test2',

'test3'

Is there a way to use split or rename a list separated with returns? I cant get this array to work.

```
$names =
"test
test2
test3"

foreach($name in $names){
    $name = "'$name,'"
        [Array]$list += $name                               
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$names` isn't an array, it's a multi-line string.

So you can split on newlines to get an array.

```
$names =
"test
test2
test3"

$splitnames = $names -split "`r?`n"
$splitnames
```

Comment: Thanks, can you provide any more info on what the r and n are doing?

Comment: @Garrett they are escape sequences for carriage return and newline characters, check out the [`about_Special_Characters` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7#new-line-n)

Comment: Nicely done; @Garrett: in order to deal with both CRLF and LF-only newlines (which in the case of an in-script string literal depends on how the enclosing script file was saved), you can use the following variation: `$names -split '\r?\n'`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer with Unix newline compatibility.